# japanese verb for "to surf the internet"

Tags: words, slang, word-requests

What are the Japanese words which express surfing the internet/browsing the internet/being on the internet both formal and informal? I stumbled upon this problem while trying to find a way to say "I browse the internet on my phone before going to sleep" (yes, I know it's unhealthy, I'm trying to stop :()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- "To surf the internet" is *literally* **ネットサーフィンする**. And I think this is sort of informal.
- "To browse" is **見る**. So **ネットを見る** is the answer.
- "Being on the internet" - either one above should be fine.

We also say:

- **インターネットに接続{せつぞく}する** *formal!*

  - This could also mean *connecting* to the internet.
- **インターネットを閲覧{えつらん}する** *formal!*

  - This always means surfing/browsing the internet.
- インターネットをする

etc.